# Is my proof that πe is transcendental correct?

Tags: proof-verification, transcendental-numbers

I've been trying to prove that πe (the product of π and e) is transcendental.
e can be defined as the infinite sum of reversed values of factorials (1/0!+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...). Hence, πe = π(1/0!+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...) = π/0!+π/1!+π/2!+π/3!+... Each number in this infinite series (π/0!, π/1! etc.) is transcendental (it's always π divided by an integer so it is transcendental because π is), so the sum of the infinite series (which equals πe) must be transcendental as well.
Can anyone check my proof and say whether it is correct or not?

Comment: A transcendental number plus another transcendental number is not necessarily transcendental itself.,  An infinite sum of transcendental numbers is again not necessarily transcendental either.  For obvious counterexample, both $\pi$ and $-\pi$ are trasncendental, however $\pi + (-\pi)=0$ is obviously not

Comment: It is not. Let $a_n=\frac1{\pi^2n^2}$. Then each $a_n$ is trancendental, and yet $\sum a_n=\frac16$ (even though all partial sums are also transcendental)

Comment: So as $\pi^{-2}$ is transcendental, so is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi^{-2}}{n^2}$?

Comment: Also, your proof could be adapted to show that $e\cdot\frac1e$ is transcendental ...

Comment: The proof is wrong, as pointed out already, and the problem is still open. In fact, it's not even known if $\pi \cdot e$ is irrational, see for example [Irrationality of $ \pi e, \pi^{\pi}$ and $e^{\pi^2}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pi-e-pi-pi-and-e-pi2).

Comment: By that logic $1=e*\frac 1e=\sum e^{-1}/n! $ is transcendental.  And by your reasoning as each $1/k! $ is rational the sum would be too. So e is rational.  Conclusions of infinite sums like that, don't work.

Answer (score 10):

No, that argument is not correct. Being transcendental is not preserved under sums: e.g. $\pi+(-\pi)$ certainly isn't transcendental!

Infinite sums only ever make things worse, not better, so the fact that a finite sum of transcendentals isn't necessarily transcendental should convince you that your argument is incorrect; but just to drive the point home, here's an example of a sequence all of whose terms are transcendental (indeed, all of whose partial sums are transendental) whose sum is $1$: $$(1-\pi)+(\pi-{\pi\over 2})+({\pi\over 2}-{\pi\over 3})+({\pi\over 3}-{\pi\over 4})+...$$

---

In general, *negative* properties like irrationality, transcendentality, etc. aren't preserved under sums - *positive* ones, like rationality, algebraicity, etc. tend to be.

Comment: That concluding remark is a very insightful observation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not to mention.  As $\pi $ and $e $ both have infinite sum expansions then $1= e*e^{-1} = e^{-1}(\sum 1/n!)=\sum e^{-1}/n! $.  The terms are transcendental.